# Iterating the the ODE for Bessel function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions

If we look at the Bessel ODE:
$$x^2 y'' + xy' + (x^2 - \alpha^2)y = 0$$

Suppose I then put the solution to the above ODE as $J_{\alpha}(x)$ in the RHS, and try to solve the following ODE:
$$x^2 y'' + xy' + (x^2 - \alpha^2)y = J_{\alpha}(x)$$
Obviously the solution to this equation is the solution to the homogeneous equation plus a specific solution.

Suppose I want to reiterate this procedure of inserting in the RHS of Bessel ODE the solution to the previous equation iteratively.

What would the solution at the $n$-th step will look like?

This is a pure math exercise I am thinking about, I don't think that someone thought of this before.

You can of course generalize it to any special function you might think of with a suitable ODE that defines it.

Comment: How are you choosing which solution to take at each step? are you setting some initial data for $y,y'$?

Comment: No, I am not setting initial data. By choosing a solution, I assume in each iteration that the homogeneous ode is solved by $J_{\alpha}$.

Comment: That's fine, but how are you choosing what the inhomogenous term is? Any possible solution could be the "specific term" you mention; you need some way to decide which one you are taking.

Comment: @SamZbarsky let's assume something like: $y(-\alpha)=0$ and $y(\alpha)=1$ for all the iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Using Variation of Parameters, your inhomogeneous equation has a particular solution

$$ \frac{\pi}{2} \left( {{Y}_{\alpha}\left(x\right)}
\int \!{\frac { {{J}_{\alpha}\left(x\right)}  ^{2}}{
x}}\,{\rm d}x- J_\alpha(x) \int \!{\frac {{{ Y}_{\alpha}\left(x\right)}{{ J}
_{\alpha}\left(x\right)}}{x}}\,{\rm d}x \right) 
$$

Comment: How would you find the solution to the $n$-th iteration of my problem?

Comment: If $F_n$ is a particular solution to the $n$'th iteration, you can take
$$F_{n+1}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} \left( Y_\alpha(x) \int \frac{J_\alpha(x) F_n(x)}{x}\; dx - J_\alpha(x) \int \frac{Y_\alpha(x) F_n(x)}{x}\; dx \right)$$
You may be able to use integration by parts to reduce iterated integrals to single integrals, but things are going to get ugly...

Comment: by all means let get ugly... :-D